# T-SQL reflection on parameters

Tags: t-sql, reflection

is it possible to use some kind of reflection on parameters in T-SQL module (function,procedure)?

```
procedure x(@foo nvarchar(max),@bar nvarchar(max)) ... 
set @foo = isnull(@foo,0); 
set @bar = isnull(@bar,0);
```

would it be possible to iterate over my parameters and set their values in a loop? Or do I need to use SQLCLR for this?

Comment: Just wondering why you would need something like this. Surely declaring optional parameters would be enough (and `if` statements can augment any logic requirements you have).

Comment: @Oded - because I was too lazy to type some stuff for 10 parameters :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've so many parameters that you need to programatically enumerate them then you probably have too many parameters! Maybe switching to an alternative data structure such as a table valued parameter or an XML document would give you a cleaner way to get such complex data into your procedures/functions?

However, if you have some very special need for this then take a look at [sys.parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx) (assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or later).

Comment: amazing! select sys.parameters.name from sys.parameters join sys.schemas join sys.all_objects ... gives at least names of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any direct way, but you might find procedure

```
sp_executesql
```

useful, its like the exec function in most interpretted languages (run code from 'string').  Probably not the safest or most popular answer, but it could be powerful.  What exactly are you trying to do?  I can't really be too much more specific (or even sure this will help!) with what you've said so far.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140516160425/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pnayak/archive/2007/05/03/how-to-use-parameter-in-tsql-to-actually-use-it-as-identifier-rather-than-the-value.aspx)